Spring Boot WebFlux - how to NOT have "data: " in streaming output to client?
I'm using Spring Boot version 2.7.10 with WebFlux.
I have a list of Objects which I wanted to iterate over each element in the list, for each element, serialize the object to JSON and emit the JSON {...} to web browser client.
Here is the Spring Controller code:
@RequestMapping(path = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
public void Flux<String> createFluxForCoverageOrLayerObject(List<Object> objects) throws PetascopeException {
        Flux<String> result =
                Flux.fromIterable(objects)
                    .map(object -> {
                        String jsonObj = this.createProprietaryObjectInJson(object);
                        return Optional.of(jsonObj);
                    })
                    .filter(Optional::isPresent)  // Filter out Optional.empty() values
                    .map(Optional::get)  // Unwrap the value from the Optional
                    .concatWith(Mono.just("Complete")) // Signal the end of the stream
                    .doOnComplete(() -> log.debug("Proprietary Capabilities stream has completed sending all items."));

        return result;
    }

On the client, I use javascript code with fetch() API, and it always have data:  as prefix in the received message.
I know this is part of SSE (Sever Send Event) standard, but how can I get rid of that data:  from serverside and it will not break the streaming feature from WebFlux?
In another words, is that mandatory to have that data: sent to client?

Do you need SSE? Look's like you should rather be doing "basic streaming" as in HTTP chunked.

@GaëlJ yes, because the list has large numbers of Object, it will take long time before clients can receive everything to display, so it needs streaming.

Sure. But SSE is not streaming. You can do streaming without doing SSE. I would not even categorize SSE as streaming at all. Look at HTTP chunked. I don't know Spring annotations but I'd guess it's just a matter of changing the produces in your code sample.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39889052/why-use-server-sent-events-instead-of-simple-http-chunked-streaming, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42559928/what-is-the-difference-between-http-streaming-and-server-sent-events

no you cant get rid of "data:" as it is part of the protocol so that the receiving client, knows what part of the message is data. If you try to remove it, it will break the protocol. Why do you even want to remove it, please give us a proper reason

@Toerktumlare I think it is nicer for client to not print the prefix data:, but I guess it was designed in the standard for some purposes so in the end, I decided to keep it as it is.

i suggest you read the standard for the format
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events#event_stream_format

As data: belongs to standard, so I decided to keep it as it is, and in the client, it can replace that data: by empty string when it received the message.
